# Extending time series

Tags: r, timestamp, time-series

I originally had flow data at 15 minute interval that looked like this

```
structure(list(t = structure(c(1136062800, 1136063700, 1136064600, 
1136065500, 1136066400, 1136067300, 1136068200, 1136069100, 1136070000, 
1136070900, 1136071800, 1136072700, 1136073600, 1136074500, 1136075400, 
1136076300, 1136077200, 1136078100, 1136079000, 1136079900, 1136080800, 
1136081700, 1136082600, 1136083500, 1136084400, 1136085300, 1136086200, 
1136087100, 1136088000, 1136088900, 1136089800, 1136090700), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "EST"), flow = c(23, 31, 42, 59, 59, 59, 50, 
48, 37, 33, 31, 31, 30, 30, 27, 27, 30, 31, 33, 37, 38, 42, 42, 
48, 48, 46, 42, 38, 37, 35, 33, 35)), .Names = c("t", "flow"), row.names = 35003:35034, class = "data.frame")
```

I cut this data into a 2 hourly average data timeseries using this code

`data <- data.frame(t=streamflowDateTime,flow=streamflow)
data2hr <- data
data2hr$time <- cut(data2hr$t,breaks="2 hours")
smoothedData <- aggregate(flow~time,data2hr,mean)`

Now I want to extend the 'smoothedData' time series by making it an hourly timeseries, but I want the new time series to retain its values from the smoothedData time series at the 2 hour intervals and I want average hourly data from the original data to be inserted in between the existing timeseries. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this result by using function `approxfun`.

First, let's convert the `time` column in `smoothedData` back to the POSIX time format:

```
smoothedData$time <- as.POSIXct(smoothedData$time)
#                  time   flow
# 1 2005-12-31 16:00:00 46.375
# 2 2005-12-31 18:00:00 30.750
# 3 2005-12-31 20:00:00 37.625
# 4 2005-12-31 22:00:00 39.250
```

Then, create an hour-separated time series:

```
data1hr <- data.frame(time=seq(min(smoothedData$time),max(smoothedData$time),by='1 hour'))
```

...make an interpolation function, which will be used to calculate average values in between two-hour intervals of the `smoothedData` data set:

```
interp.time <- approxfun(x=smoothedData$time,y=smoothedData$flow)
```

and, finally, apply this function to the hour-separated time series:

```
data1hr$flow <- interp.time(data1hr$time)
#                  time    flow
# 1 2005-12-31 16:00:00 46.3750
# 2 2005-12-31 17:00:00 38.5625
# 3 2005-12-31 18:00:00 30.7500
# 4 2005-12-31 19:00:00 34.1875
# 5 2005-12-31 20:00:00 37.6250
# 6 2005-12-31 21:00:00 38.4375
# 7 2005-12-31 22:00:00 39.2500
```

**EDIT**

In the light of the OP's comment,

> I feel like i explained my issue in a way more complicated than it has
>   to be. Basically, at the even number hour timestamps, i.e. 00:00:00,
>   02:00:00 I want 2 hourly averages, but at odd number hour timestamps
>   01:00:00, 03:00:00 I want hourly averages

I'd like to propose another solution to the problem:

```
data <- structure(list(t = structure(c(1136062800, 1136063700, 1136064600,
1136065500, 1136066400, 1136067300, 1136068200, 1136069100, 1136070000,
1136070900, 1136071800, 1136072700, 1136073600, 1136074500, 1136075400,
1136076300, 1136077200, 1136078100, 1136079000, 1136079900, 1136080800,
1136081700, 1136082600, 1136083500, 1136084400, 1136085300, 1136086200,
1136087100, 1136088000, 1136088900, 1136089800, 1136090700), class = c("POSIXct",
"POSIXt"), tzone = "EST"), flow = c(23, 31, 42, 59, 59, 59, 50,
48, 37, 33, 31, 31, 30, 30, 27, 27, 30, 31, 33, 37, 38, 42, 42,
48, 48, 46, 42, 38, 37, 35, 33, 35)), .Names = c("t", "flow"), row.names = 35003:35034, class = "data.frame")

data2hr <- data
data2hr$time <- cut(data2hr$t,breaks="2 hours")
smoothedData2hr <- aggregate(flow~time,data2hr,mean)
#                 time   flow
# 1 2005-12-31 16:00:00 46.375
# 2 2005-12-31 18:00:00 30.750
# 3 2005-12-31 20:00:00 37.625
# 4 2005-12-31 22:00:00 39.250

data1hr <- data
data1hr$time <- cut(data1hr$t,breaks="1 hour")
smoothedData1hr <- aggregate(flow~time,data1hr,mean)
#                  time  flow
# 1 2005-12-31 16:00:00 38.75
# 2 2005-12-31 17:00:00 54.00
# 3 2005-12-31 18:00:00 33.00
# 4 2005-12-31 19:00:00 28.50
# 5 2005-12-31 20:00:00 32.75
# 6 2005-12-31 21:00:00 42.50
# 7 2005-12-31 22:00:00 43.50
# 8 2005-12-31 23:00:00 35.00

result <- smoothedData1hr
result$flow[match(smoothedData2hr$time,result$time)] <- smoothedData2hr$flow
#                  time   flow
# 1 2005-12-31 16:00:00 46.375
# 2 2005-12-31 17:00:00 54.000
# 3 2005-12-31 18:00:00 30.750
# 4 2005-12-31 19:00:00 28.500
# 5 2005-12-31 20:00:00 37.625
# 6 2005-12-31 21:00:00 42.500
# 7 2005-12-31 22:00:00 39.250
# 8 2005-12-31 23:00:00 35.000
```

Comment: I dont want interpolated data since I actually have data for that timestep in the original data so I want to take average of the hourly timesteps that are missing in the 2 hourly timeseries and then merge them!

Comment: Why don't you just use `data2hr$time <- cut(data2hr$t,breaks="1 hour")` then?

Comment: I feel like i explained my issue in a way more complicated than it has to be. Basically, at the even number hour timestamps, i.e. 00:00:00, 02:00:00 I want 2 hourly averages, but at odd number hour timestamps 01:00:00, 03:00:00 I want hourly averages

Comment: Oh, I see. Then, you can produce a one-hour averaged data set (e.g. `smoothedData1h`) and replace even-hour records in it by the matching records from the `smoothedData` data set that you already have.

Comment: Yes exactly, thats what I am trying to do but cant seem to find a way to do it!